# Trying to set data-live-search to select-picker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

selectpicker

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
$("#s1").addClass("btn-sm");
//set to current value$("#s1").selectpicker('val', picker[0]["f_name"]);
$("#s1").selectpicker("refresh");
```

select picker css

```
<div id="input1" style="margin-bottom: 50px">
    <div class="pull-left" style="width: 250px;">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="s1"> 
        </select>
```

This is my code. I want to set a search in my select picker. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

selectpicker function should be on ready method of jquery.

Also try

```
 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true
 });
```

instead of data-live-search="true" in html.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="live-search" >
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" >
       <option data-tokens="text" >text</option>                               
     </select>
 </div>
```

You have to add
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"